# FlexJSON change property name - on Date fields

Tags: java, json, flexjson

I found this bit of code from here: [Change property name with Flexjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652231/flexjson-change-prop-name)

It works for String data types but seemingly no others. Any ideas?

```
public class FieldNameTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

    private String transformedFieldName;

    public FieldNameTransformer(String transformedFieldName) {
        this.transformedFieldName = transformedFieldName;
    }

    public void transform(Object object) {
    boolean setContext = false;

    TypeContext typeContext = getContext().peekTypeContext();

    //Write comma before starting to write field name if this
    //isn't first property that is being transformed
    if (!typeContext.isFirst())
        getContext().writeComma();

    typeContext.setFirst(false);

    getContext().writeName(getTransformedFieldName());
    getContext().writeQuoted((String) object);

    if (setContext) {
        getContext().writeCloseObject();
    }
}

/***
 * TRUE tells the JSONContext that this class will be handling 
 * the writing of our property name by itself. 
 */
@Override
public Boolean isInline() {
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}

public String getTransformedFieldName() {
    return this.transformedFieldName;
}
}
```

This works fine for text fields but gets very unhappy if I try to apply it to a field that is a date. For example:

```
    String JSON = new JSONSerializer()
        .include("type", "createDate")
        .exclude("*")
        .transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy"), Date.class)
        .transform(new FieldNameTransformer("new_json_property_name"),"createDate")
        .serialize(stuff);
```

Fails with JSONException occured : Error trying to deepSerialize

It works fine when I comment out the transform new Field... line and it works fine when I try to change the type field, which is a String.

It also fails when trying to modify and Int and I would expect everything else that's not a String.

If someone is familiar with the FlexJSON API and can point me in the right direction here I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to change this part of the code:

```
getContext().writeQuoted((String) object);
```

For most types it should work if you change it to:

```
getContext().writeQuoted(object.toString());
```

If that does not work for Date values - just rewrite integrating a SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
getContext().writeQuoted(sdf.format(object));
```

That should do the trick.