# FlexJson and @JSON annotation - @JSON(name = "") not working

Tags: java, annotations, flexjson

I just switched to FlexJson and I am already having a problem.

The documentation at http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/, chapter `Controlling JSON naming with @JSON` states :

> When an object is serialized the names of the properties on JSON
>   objects are determined from the name of the Java property. This means
>   the names of the getter methods or the field names are used. However,
>   sometimes the JSON output doesn't match the names used by the Java
>   object. You can control this using the @JSON annotation. For example:

```
    public class Species {
        @JSON(jsonName = "genus")
        private String type;

        private String name;

        @JSON(jsonName="species")
        public String getName() {
           return name;
        }
    }
```

Except it doesn't work. And then they say :

> Defining a @JSON.jsonName is used in both serialization and
>   deserialization.

Now when I have a look into the javadocs at http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html, I can see there are 4 optional elements belonging to the @JSON annotation, those are

> include name objectFactory transformer

None of it is `jsonName`, like in the example.

So how do I get this annotation to work, so I can have different java and json names?
How can I define this annotation element or make use of the predefined `name`

To clarify, I can annotate `@JSON` and autocomplete recommends `@JSON(include)`, but then `include` cannot be resolved...

I am using FlexJson 2.1, and I imported flexjson.JSON;

Btw I am aware of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8879616/2001247, but it's not what I want. I want to use annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **FlexJson 3.2**

The problem is, latest jar accessible via developer site have 2.1 version number.
But java doc corresponds to version 3.2.
You can find FlexJson 3.2 jar in maven repository.

Comment: Glad this was heplful for you)

Comment: I tried changing the version to 3.2 and also 3.3, but still it's not working.